# Trim Spaces inside whole Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, trim

How to trim spaces inside all table's column values from particular Database?

It has to `LTrim` & `RTrim` spaces inside row column values from all tables in Database. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below one

```
     DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
        SET @SQL = ''

         SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'UPDATE T SET T.'+IC.COLUMN_NAME + 
                          ' = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + IC.COLUMN_NAME+')) 
                          FROM '+ IT.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' + IT.TABLE_NAME +
                          '] AS T ;' + CHAR(13)
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IT
            JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC ON IT.TABLE_NAME = IC.TABLE_NAME
            AND IT.TABLE_SCHEMA = IC.TABLE_SCHEMA AND IT.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
and IC.DATA_TYPE in( 'varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar')

        Exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Go'.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'UPDATE ' +  IT.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.[' 
              + IT.TABLE_NAME + ']' 
              + 'SET '+IC.COLUMN_NAME
              + ' = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + IC.COLUMN_NAME+')) ' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IT
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC ON IT.TABLE_NAME = IC.TABLE_NAME
AND IT.TABLE_SCHEMA = IC.TABLE_SCHEMA

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: It is giving me error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')) 
FROM dbo.[Categories] AS T
UPDATE T SET T.CategoryName = LTRIM(RTRIM(CategoryName'.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Go'.

Comment: Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update identity column 'Id'.

Comment: I think we have to ignore primary key & foreign key column's?? right??

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type image is invalid for argument 1 of rtrim function.

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of rtrim function.

Comment: Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update identity column 'diagram_id'.

Comment: is it like .. the query should pick only the char / varchar/nchar/nvarchar columns..

Comment: yes... It should only include those column's whose datatype is char,varchar/nchar etc as you mentioned..

Answer (score 1):

Please try using below script to trim the space by specifying the table name

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
SET @TableName = 'TableName'

SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ',[', '[') + 
COLUMN_NAME + ']=RTRIM([' + COLUMN_NAME + '])'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
--AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' /*If any condition in my case its varchar*/

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE [' + @TableName + '] SET ' + @SQL
PRINT @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Godd.. i almost sweated doing this :D

This will loop through all tables in your DB, and generate & execute query to trim all columns in it

```
DECLARE @tablename as nvarchar(100)=''
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

DECLARE tempcursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN tempcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM tempcursor 
INTO @tablename


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    if exists (select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
                where t.name = @tablename and collation_name is not null)
    BEGIN
        set @sql = @sql + 'update '+ @tablename + ' SET '

        select @sql = @sql + c.name + '= LTRIM(RTRIM(' + c.name + ')) ,'
        from sys.columns c
        inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
        where t.name = @tablename
        and collation_name is not null
        and is_ansi_padded = 1
        and is_computed = 0

        SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM tempcursor 
    INTO @tablename
END 
CLOSE tempcursor;
DEALLOCATE tempcursor;

print @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Remember the limit of 8000 characters for SQL Query string variable (i.e. @sql)

Comment: Please check comment's of Deepshika's answer

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables having view information, and there is no condition to restrict to pulling view in your list.

Comment: Check now.. it will only trim tables , only columns which are text based

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh Yes Now it's perfectly working... but my question is why to use cursor if we can do it with a single statement.. What you say??

Comment: Cursor is to loop through tables in db, how else you think we can do that ?

Comment: Plus this query is maximized to reduce content in Query String. for e.g. instead of 'update tbl set col1 = trim(col1) update tbl set col 2 = trim (col2)'
i have done 'update tbl set col1= trim(col1) , col2 = trim (col2)' and so on..

Comment: But still this is having issues with Trigger's.. I don't know where it is comming from.. Values are getting updated but not perfectly... Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xyz, Line 43
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I though of it, avoiding doesn't mean 'not using', It should be avoided with transnational statements, anyways as long as we are not executing anything inside cursor, we are fine.

Comment: Query should not be a problem, I think you will have to trace to that table and check for the trigger.
Also this is not impacting data in that sense, you can disable triggers and later re enable them.

Comment: I also have lot's of Trigger's & stored procedures in my DB.. I can not do enable & disable on this...

Comment: Hmm can you identify which trigger is this ?

Answer (score 1):

This Solved my issue :

```
    DECLARE @SQL AS VarChar(MAX)
    SET @SQL = ''

    SELECT @SQL += 'UPDATE ' +  IT.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' 
                  + QUOTENAME(IT.TABLE_NAME) + 
                  + 'SET '+IC.COLUMN_NAME
                  + ' = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + IC.COLUMN_NAME+')) ' + CHAR(13)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IT
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC ON IT.TABLE_NAME = IC.TABLE_NAME
    AND IT.TABLE_SCHEMA = IC.TABLE_SCHEMA AND IC.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','char','varchar','nchar')

    EXEC (@SQL)
```

*Reference :* Deepshikha's answer.. Thanks Deepshikha