# Function in Pgadmin Throws operator does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, function

I modified the function to trim all values in multiple tables based on [Trim Spaces inside whole Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449526/trim-spaces-inside-whole-database) as below:

```
create function trim_all_text()
RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE QL VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    QL ='';
    -- stored procedure body
        PERFORM QL = QL || 'UPDATE T SET T.'||IC.COLUMN_NAME || 
                          ' = LTRIM(RTRIM(' || IC.COLUMN_NAME||')) 
                          FROM '|| IT.TABLE_SCHEMA || '.[' || IT.TABLE_NAME ||
                          '] AS T ;' || CHR(13)
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IT
            JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC ON IT.TABLE_NAME = IC.TABLE_NAME
            AND IT.TABLE_SCHEMA ='public' and IT.TABLE_SCHEMA = IC.TABLE_SCHEMA AND IT.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
and IC.DATA_TYPE in( 'varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar', 'text');

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run the function in pgadmin4, I receive the error below:
ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + information_schema.sql_identifier
LINE 1: SELECT QL += 'UPDATE ' +  IT.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.'
^

How can I combine strings in a query?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) the string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`. And there is no `+=` [assignment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) in PL/pgSQL either

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code. It runs, but no rows updated. did I miss anything from the code?

Comment: I'm guessing you have no tables in public...  can you verify?

Comment: Postgres does not use the [...] convention to indicate maintaining case (MS Sql Server only?), it iser the SQL standard double quote ("). If that is your intention then `... FROM '|| IT.TABLE_SCHEMA || '."' || IT.TABLE_NAME || ': AS T ;'`